# form wizard initial data for edit not loading properly in Django?

Tags: django, django-forms, django-views, django-formwizard

I have a three page form-list coming out of a single model. I could save the model first time, but when I want to edit the model, only the first form shows the initial value, subsequent forms does not show the initial data.  but when I print the `initial_dict` from views, I can see all the initial views correctly. I followed this [blog](http://nickbewley.com/development/editable-formwizard-in-django/) on form wizard.

Here is my `model.py:`

```
class Item(models.Model):
    user=models.ForeignKey(User)
    price=models.DecimalField(max_digits=8,decimal_places=2)
    image=models.ImageField(upload_to="assets/", blank=True)
    description=models.TextField(blank=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return '%s-%s' %(self.user.username, self.price)
```

urls.py:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',

url(r'^create/$', MyWizard.as_view([FirstForm, SecondForm, ThirdForm]), name='wizards'),
url(r'^edit/(?P<id>\d+)/$', 'formwizard.views.edit_wizard', name='edit_wizard'),
)
```

forms.py:

```
class FirstForm(forms.Form):
    id = forms.IntegerField(widget=forms.HiddenInput, required=False)
    price = forms.DecimalField(max_digits=8, decimal_places=2)
    #add all the fields that you want to include in the form

class SecondForm(forms.Form):
    image = forms.ImageField(required=False)

class ThirdForm(forms.Form):
    description = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Textarea)
```

views.py:

```
class MyWizard(SessionWizardView):
    template_name = "wizard_form.html"
    file_storage = FileSystemStorage(location=os.path.join(settings.MEDIA_ROOT))
    #if you are uploading files you need to set FileSystemStorage
    def done(self, form_list, **kwargs):
        for form in form_list:
           print form.initial
        if not self.request.user.is_authenticated():
                raise Http404
        id = form_list[0].cleaned_data['id']
        try:
                item = Item.objects.get(pk=id)
                ######################   SAVING ITEM   #######################
                item.save()
                print item
                instance = item
        except:
                item = None
                instance = None
        if item and item.user != self.request.user:
                print "about to raise 404"
                raise Http404
        if not item:
                instance = Item()
                for form in form_list:
                    for field, value in form.cleaned_data.iteritems():
                        setattr(instance, field, value)
                instance.user = self.request.user
                instance.save()
            return render_to_response('wizard-done.html', {
                'form_data': [form.cleaned_data for form in form_list], })


    def edit_wizard(request, id):
        #get the object
        item = get_object_or_404(Item, pk=id)
        #make sure the item belongs to the user
        if item.user != request.user:
            raise HttpResponseForbidden()
        else:
            #get the initial data to include in the form
            initial = {'0': {'id': item.id,
                             'price': item.price,
                             #make sure you list every field from your form definition here to include it later in the initial_dict
            },
                       '1': {'image': item.image,
                       },
                       '2': {'description': item.description,
                       },
            }
            print initial
            form = MyWizard.as_view([FirstForm, SecondForm, ThirdForm], initial_dict=initial)
            return form(context=RequestContext(request), request=request)
```

template:

```
<html>
<body>
<h2>Contact Us</h2>
  <p>Step {{ wizard.steps.step1 }} of {{ wizard.steps.count }}</p>
  {% for field in form %}
    {{field.error}}
  {% endfor %}

  <form action={% url 'wizards' %} method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">{% csrf_token %}
  <table>
  {{ wizard.management_form }}
  {% if wizard.form.forms %}
      {{ wizard.form.management_form }}
      {% for form in wizard.form.forms %}
          {{ form }}
      {% endfor %}
  {% else %}
      {{ wizard.form }}
  {% endif %}
  </table>
  {% if wizard.steps.prev %}
  <button name="wizard_goto_step" type="submit" value="{{ wizard.steps.first }}">"first step"</button>
  <button name="wizard_goto_step" type="submit" value="{{ wizard.steps.prev }}">"prev step"</button>
  {% endif %}


  <input type="submit" value="Submit" />

  </form>

</body>
</html>
```

EDIT:
one this I noticed is the following:
On the edit mode, i.e, when I am at the following url : `http://127.0.0.1:8000/wizard/edit/1/`,
it displays the first form data correctly, and when I click submit, it is not taking me to step-2 of edit mode, i.e the URL changes to `http://127.0.0.1:8000/wizard/create/`.

If upon clicking `submit` on edit url (like `/wizard/edit/1`) in the first step, same url is maintained then the form would get its initial data in next step. but I cannot figure out how to avoid the url from changing to `/wizard/create`

Comment: One problem I see is you don't need to pass `RequestContext()` to wizard view call, so try removing that.

Comment: @Rohan I tried removing `RequestContext()` but that did not help

Comment: @Rohan: I added some more information in the edit. I am hoping you can help out. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error looks trivial. In your template the form action has `wizards` url, which is url of *create* view. Hence when the form is submitted it goes to `/wizard/create`.

To able to use the template for both views, you can remove the `action` attribute from `form` tag. The form will be submitted to current url which can be create or edit.

So change your template to have `form` tag as

```
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

---

EDIT: To save item

Update your view as:

```
def done(self, form_list, **kwargs):
        for form in form_list:
           print form.initial
        if not self.request.user.is_authenticated():
                raise Http404
        id = form_list[0].cleaned_data['id']
        try:
                item = Item.objects.get(pk=id)
                print item
                instance = item
        except:
                item = None
                instance = None
        if item and item.user != self.request.user:
                print "about to raise 404"
                raise Http404
        if not item:
                instance = Item()

        #moved for out of if
        for form in form_list:
            for field, value in form.cleaned_data.iteritems():
                setattr(instance, field, value)
        instance.user = self.request.user
        instance.save()

        return render_to_response('wizard-done.html', {
                'form_data': [form.cleaned_data for form in form_list], })
```

Comment: Thanks, that helped. but in the edit mode, the model is not overwritten. That is changes are not saved. can you help with what is wrong?

Comment: @brainstorm, in your view, if you get `item` you don't actually use it  to save.

Comment: Thanks for commenting, I have inserted `item.save()` in the `done method` now (you can see in the code above). but that did not save the editing the model. Do you think I should save the `item` somewhere else?

Comment: :worked like a charm. Thank you very much. you might be able to help me with this post: you already commented on this post. but I am seeing two copies of images being uploaded (one to fileStorage and one to upload path). how to avoid that? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24176068/two-copies-of-images-are-stored-each-time-i-upload-an-image-in-django