# two copies of images are stored each time I upload an image in django?

Tags: django, django-models, django-media

when I upload an image, i see it uploaded twice in my project. The two locations are 
`/Users/myproject/media/` and `/Users/myproject/media/assets/uploaded_files/username/`. I expect the image to be uploaded only to the latter. why two copies are uploaded and how to avoid it?

In `settings.py:`

```
MEDIA_URL="/media/"

MEDIA_ROOT = '/Users/myproject/media/'
```

Here is models.py

```
UPLOAD_FILE_PATTERN="assets/uploaded_files/%s/%s_%s"

def get_upload_file_name(instance, filename):
    date_str=datetime.now().strftime("%Y/%m/%d").replace('/','_')
    return UPLOAD_FILE_PATTERN % (instance.user.username,date_str,filename)

class Item(models.Model):
    user=models.ForeignKey(User)
    price=models.DecimalField(max_digits=8,decimal_places=2)
    image=models.ImageField(upload_to=get_upload_file_name, blank=True)
    description=models.TextField(blank=True)
```

EDIT:
I am using formwizards. Here is the views.py:

```
class MyWizard(SessionWizardView):
    template_name = "wizard_form.html"
    file_storage = FileSystemStorage(location=os.path.join(settings.MEDIA_ROOT))
    #if you are uploading files you need to set FileSystemStorage
    def done(self, form_list, **kwargs):
        for form in form_list:
           print form.initial
        if not self.request.user.is_authenticated():
            raise Http404
        id = form_list[0].cleaned_data['id']
        try:
            item = Item.objects.get(pk=id)
            print item
            instance = item
        except:
            item = None
            instance = None
        if item and item.user != self.request.user:
            print "about to raise 404"
            raise Http404
        if not item:
            instance = Item()
            for form in form_list:
                for field, value in form.cleaned_data.iteritems():
                    setattr(instance, field, value)
            instance.user = self.request.user
            instance.save()
        return render_to_response('wizard-done.html', {
            'form_data': [form.cleaned_data for form in form_list], })


def edit_wizard(request, id):
    #get the object
    item = get_object_or_404(Item, pk=id)
    #make sure the item belongs to the user
    if item.user != request.user:
        raise HttpResponseForbidden()
    else:
        #get the initial data to include in the form
        initial = {'0': {'id': item.id,
                         'price': item.price,
                         #make sure you list every field from your form definition here to include it later in the initial_dict
        },
                   '1': {'image': item.image,
                   },
                   '2': {'description': item.description,
                   },
        }
        print initial
        form = MyWizard.as_view([FirstForm, SecondForm, ThirdForm], initial_dict=initial)
        return form(context=RequestContext(request), request=request)
```

Comment: Can you add your view code that's passing the image along?

Comment: @schillingt: I have pasted the views.py above. I am using formwizard in the views. I noticed that I have file_storage in the wizard class above. That is probably causing it. but wizard class requires file storage, otherwise they don't function

Answer (score 0):

According to the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/contrib/formtools/form-wizard/#wizard-files), you need to clean up the temporary images yourself, which is what's happening to you.

Here's an [issue](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/22299#comment:5) that was just merged into master and backported. You can try calling `storage.reset` after finishing all of the successful processing.

Comment: Doc says you need to remove files when wizard does not complete successfully. If it does, files will be removed.

Comment: I do not see any storage.reset handler in the docs you linked.and as Rohan mentions it is not needed if wizard completes successfully

Comment: @Rohan: my wizard completes successfully. I could log in the admin and see the model saved. but I have a related issue when I load the wizard for edit view. More here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24173367/form-wizard-initial-data-for-edit-not-loading-properly-in-django